# Chapter and Section format

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, formatting, chapters

I want my chapter titles to look as they would with the code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\centering
 CHAPTER II \\
 SUBSQUARES

\end{document}
```

Centered all caps and with roman numeral numbering.  I have tried `titlesec` and
`\renewcommand`.  Apparently, I do not understand the parameters of `\titleformat`
well enough to  get it to do what I want.  I can get something close with
`\renewcommand` however the chapter numbers do not increment.  Any help is
very appreciated.

```
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\uppercase{CHAPTER} {\Roman{chapter}}  \\}
```

Comment: Look at the `sectsty` package, or look on this site for examples of `titlesec` usage. Since you are using the `book` class, you might consider switching to `memoir`, which provides its own interface for adjusting the headings (or a KOMA class for the same reason). There is too much built-in code (for spacing, font, counters, etc.) in the original definition of the section headings to alter them simply with a `\renewcommand`.

Comment: Do you want the same (centering + CAPITAL LETTERS) for `\section`? What about `\subsection`...?

Answer (score 6):

I think that using the `sectsty` package is simpler.

Just add the following lines to your preamble

```
\usepackage{sectsty}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\chapterfont{\centering\MakeUppercase}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\chapterfont{\centering\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Unnumbered Chapter}

\chapter{Numbered Chapter}

\appendix

\chapter{An Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a crude way of implementing your requirement. It uses [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch the macros responsible for creating the chapter headings. There are two macros, one for `\chapter` and one for `\chapter*`. In each of these macros, an adjustment is made to the chapter title (argument `#1`) as well as the horizontal alignment - changing from `\raggedright` to `\centering`. As such, a total of 4 patches are made.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{\MakeUppercase{Chapter}}
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<succes>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{First chapter}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\end{document}
```

The other changes to `\thechapter` sets the output to print a `\Roman` format of the `chapter` counter, while an adjustment to `\@chappapp` sets the `Chapter` prefix in CAPITAL LETTERS. This may need some minor adjustments if you also have an Appendix chapter.